# how do i unlink a google cloud platform project from firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am working on firebase and google cloud platform, recently I linked my google cloud project with firebase, now I want to unlink it from firebase. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a "link".  When you import a GCP project into the Firebase console, all you've done is import Firebase APIs and services into that project.  If you don't want to use those APIs, then there's no problem.  You won't be billed for APIs you don't use.  If you want to disable the APIs in the Cloud console, then you're free to do so.

Comment: "Link" vs "enable" is semantics, the question remains, can the API's be disabled after they have been enabled? (I'm pretty sure the answer is 'no')

Comment: @JWAspin Have you tried?  There should be a simple toggle switch for each API that gives you this control.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is there a way to remove the project from firebase console? But keep all the GCP settings (I have a maps API key). If I try to delete the project from firebase, it gives the warning that it will also delete the GCP project. Thanks.