# How to remove Firebase project without deleting entire GCP project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I originally had a Google Cloud project with some APIs enabled for Maps and a few other services.

Later, I wanted to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging, so I created a new Firebase project and linked it to the Google Cloud project.

I realised later that I'd made a typo entering the Android package name when setting up Firebase Cloud Messaging. The only way to change this is to start again, so I deleted the project, but it warned me that it would delete the GCP project too. I took the chance, thinking it might just remove the Firebase services, but, no, it took the entirety of the Google Cloud project - and all the config for the services completely unrelated to Firebase - with it.

Strangely, I could still view it in Google Cloud platform, but it also appeared in 'Resources pending deletion'. I undeleted it there, and the Firebase project returned too.

I want to decouple and remove just the Firebase component of my project without it affecting the rest of the Google Cloud project.

How can I do this? It seems quite bizarre that this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is not just "a component" in GCP.  Firebase is made up of several products, each maintained separately from each other, much in the same way as other GCP products are separate from each other. They all exist in the same project container.  In a few cases, Firebase products are actually exactly the same as GCP products (Firestore, Cloud Functions, Cloud Storage), except Firebase just adds API wrappers on top of them that are useful for mobile and web application development.

The best you can do is delete whatever data is present in each product, then disable any related APIs for that product.  You will have to do this for each different product you were using that you no longer want to use. There is no "off switch" for Firebase products in relation to the GCP project that hosts them.

See also:

- [How to disable Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685684/how-to-disable-cloud-firestore)
- [How do I delete a Firebase product (or feature) from a project (e.g. Cloud Storage)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213248/how-do-i-delete-a-firebase-product-or-feature-from-a-project-e-g-cloud-stora)
- [how do i unlink a google cloud platform project from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075093/how-do-i-unlink-a-google-cloud-platform-project-from-firebase)

And read:

- **https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f**
- https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-functions-612d9e1e89cb
- https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-storage-a33fad7c2b80
- https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-firestore-40f1fc3e6d1e

Comment: I've disabled everything in 'APIs & Services' starting with 'Firebase'. The Firebase project still exists and won't let me create a new one linked to the GCP project. Do I have to literally delete the entire GCP project and start again? I haven't found a definitive answer anywhere on this, but worryingly it looks like the answer is yes.

Comment: A GCP project **IS** a Firebase project.  They are not different things.  Firebase products live alongside GCP products in the same project.  This is not something you can change.  Please read the first linked blog post for a complete explanation.  If you need to completely remove a Firebase project, then you have no choice but to delete the GCP project also, since they are the same thing.

Comment: I understood that, but in my case the GCP project existed before Firebase linked itself to it. Undoing that doesn't seem an unreasonable expectation. In any case, I've found the ability to remove the Android app within Firebase without removing Firebase completely. That should cover what I want to do.

Comment: Right, so if you want to stop using Firebase, you can "undo" it by doing what I said: delete all the data in the Firebase products and disable the APIs.  All Firebase really did when when you enabled it in your GCP project is just enable the APIs.  They are not "linked", as you say.  Firebase is just APIs within a GCP project.

Comment: They exist as independent services within GCP, but on the Firebase side they are inextricably linked in that you cannot separate Firebase without taking out your entire GCP project. Given that Firebase presents itself as a user-friendly solution, manually disabling services one by one within GCP itself seems like an overly cumbersome process.

Comment: If you have feature requests or feedback about Firebase, you can contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly.